# "Smarty" Splitting divs into multiple columns?

Tags: php, html, smarty

i need some help about smarty. I want to split my results but i couldn't make it.
When i run my code, it is like;

GAME 1
GAME 2
GAME 3
GAME 4
GAME 5
GAME 6

But i want it looks like this,

GAME 1 GAME 4 
GAME 2 GAME 5
GAME 3 GAME 6

or

GAME 1 GAME 2
GAME 3 GAME 4
GAME 5 GAME 6

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

```
    {foreach from=$newgames item=games}
<div style="height:120px; width:420px;">
<div class="gamepic">
                        <a href="{$siteadres}/{$games.seobaslik}.html" alt="{$games.baslik}" title="{$games.baslik}">
                            <img style="border:none; " src="{$games.resim}" alt="{$games.baslik}" data-original="{$games.resim}" height="100" width="100"/>
                        </a>
</div>
<div class="gamedesc">
<span class="gametitle">{$games.baslik}</span>
<div class="itemcontent">{$games.aciklama}</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom:-15px;">Played: {$games.ptime}</div><div style="float:right;"> <a href="{$siteadres}/{$games.seobaslik}.html" title="{$games.baslik}"><img style="border:none;" src="{$siteadres}/temalar/{$tema}/images/play.png"/></a></div>

</div>
</div>

            {/foreach}
```

Comment: This can be accomplished with CSS. http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Smarty3, you must use the [@index property](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index), make a module with the number of columns and insert close/open the div.

```
{* output empty row on the 4th iteration (when index is 3) *}
<table>
{foreach $items as $i}
  {if $i@index eq 3}
     {* put empty table row *}
     <tr><td>nbsp;</td></tr>
  {/if}
  <tr><td>{$i.label}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

Or with smarty 2 you must use [iteration property](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl#section.property.iteration) documentation.
:

```
<table>
{section name=co loop=$contacts}
  {if $smarty.section.co.iteration % 5 == 1}
    <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Name></th><th>Home</th><th>Cell</th><th>Email</th></tr>
  {/if}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="view.php?id={$contacts[co].id}">view<a></td>
    <td>{$contacts[co].name}</td>
    <td>{$contacts[co].home}</td>
    <td>{$contacts[co].cell}</td>
    <td>{$contacts[co].email}</td>
  <tr>
{/section}
</table>
```

As Matthew Blancarte says you can make with CSS3 [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-rule) or with this [other method](http://alistapart.com/article/css3multicolumn)